# How do I turn a ubuntu server 17.04 into a Virtual Machine Host via command line?

Tags: virtualhost

I want to use Ubuntu Servers (Physical Iron) as my Virtual Machine Hosts, what is the correct way to do this with Ubuntu? (In CentOS, you can use centos-xen), but wanted to know what Ubuntu reccomended?

I have the Ubuntu 17.04 Server ISO file, and my goal is to install a hypervisor on top of Ubuntu Server 17.04. (I am not looking for a GUI like Vmware or Virtualbox), sorry for the confusion :)

Comment: I am not 100% clear what you want to achieve. You want existing Ubuntu Servers as VM hosts? Well, as long as there is enough RAM and disk space available, then all you have to do is install a VM package like VMware or VirtualBox and create VM's. I am not sure why you mentioned you have the Server ISO file ?

Comment: PS. I don't think there is a Ubuntu recommendation. It's up to the user to select a package to their liking/experience.

Comment: Virtualbox and Vmware are not what I need, as these are GUIs. What I need is to make my Ubuntu Servers as virtual hosts. (For instance Xen or Esx are hypervisors. What is the Ubuntu Server Hypervisor reccomendation?)

Comment: See [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/virtualization.html).

Comment: @WubiUbuntu1980: ah, I see. Then indeed follow Doug's link.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much, The default virtualization technology supported in Ubuntu is KVM.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [vSphere](https://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-4-esx-vcenter/index.jsp?topic=/com.vmware.vsphere.dcadmin.doc_41/vsp_dc_admin_guide/vsp_interfaces/c_vi_web_access.html) which is a web GUI for vmware hosts